# How to call method after finishing first transaction in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

In my Spring mvc application, calling following method , when click 'Save' button in jsp page.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User u,
        BindingResult result, @ModelAttribute("category") UserCategory uc,
        BindingResult resultCat, Model model, RedirectAttributes reDctModel) {


            this.userService.addUser(u); // adding new user to DB
            reDctModel.addFlashAttribute("msgSucess","Successfully saved..!");

            this.sendEmail(u.getUsr_email(),"RDMS","Login Details");  // For sending mail



        return "redirect:/users";
    }


public String sendEmail(String recipientAddress,String subject,String message) {
       // creates a simple e-mail object
        SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();
        email.setTo(recipientAddress);
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setText(message);

        // sends the e-mail
        this.mailSender.send(email);

        return "Result";
    }
```

This is my applicationcontext

```
 </bean>
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="myemailaddress@gmail.com" />
    <property name="password" value="********" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The issue is, after adding sendEmail() ,it takes around 15 seconds to save the new record.Before adding this method it takes only 1 second.Can anybody guide me to reducing slowness of the programme or calling sendEmail() after finishing first transaction.Thanks in advance.

Comment: add a non-syncronous system for sending emails, as a JMS message queue

Comment: you can use the method sendEmail as a asynchronous by using spring annotation @Async

Comment: But e-mail will be send even though saving fails.

Comment: Ofcourse it will because that is what you programmed... Also putting this in your controller is a bad idea imho it should be part of your service call, if another mechanism web service, batch proces, calls addUser you probably also want to send an email not only when a user is created by the web.

Comment: @M.Deinum he was not me who put that in the controller :) He was chk.buddi. I just pointed one thing. In order to prevent user from this issue, sending wrong e-mail, I think s/he should send it after saving user.

Comment: Burak Keceli , M. Deinum,  Can you pls tell me , what is the exact place to call sendEmail(). If saving fails, I don't need to send this mail.Thanks for the all valuble comments.

Comment: Put it in a separate service, annotate the method with `@Async` and call it from the addUser method. But only if there is no error saving the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create async service and configure your application for asynchronous usage, here you have [spring tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/). In async service you have to place your code for sending email. Below you can see sample code for 2 classes first is service second is application class,

```
        import java.util.concurrent.Future;
        import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
        import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
        import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

        @Service
        public class SampleService {

            @Async
            public Future sendEmail(String email) {
                // here you can place your code for sending email
                return new AsyncResult("email sent successful");
            }

        }
```

```
    import java.util.concurrent.Future;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableAsync
    public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

        @Autowired
        SampleService sampleService;

        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            Future page1 = sampleService.sendEmail("test@gmail.com");
            while (!page1.isDone()) {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            System.out.println(page1.get());
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    }
```